WinUI 3 Data Grid Having Different Formatting For Each Cell Using the DataTemplateSelector Class
I'm trying to create a simple data grid in WinUI 3 that uses custom DataTemplate that vary for the second column, creating different formatting for the second column's cells depending on the data type of the cell's data. A boolean would have a CheckBox and a string would have a TextBox.
I'm extending the DataTemplateSelector class to achieve this, per this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/data-template-selector
The problem is, my extension's override DataTemplateSelectorExt.SelectTemplateCore() method shown below doesn't even run, so I can't even test if the template code is good. There are no errors, but the second column of the data grid only shows the namespace of the CustomInfo class: ...ViewModels.CustomInfo.
My first question is, what is preventing SelectTemplateCore() from running and providing the second column with a custom DataTemplate?
XAML
       <Page.Resources>
            <local:DataTemplateSelectorExt
                x:Key="templateselctor"
                CheckBoxTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplateResource}"
                TextBlockTemplate="{StaticResource TextBlockTemplateResource}"
                TextBoxTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplateResource}" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBlockTemplateResource" x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplateResource" x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{x:Bind}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplateResource" x:DataType="x:Boolean">
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{x:Bind}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
            x:Name="dataGrid1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CustomInfoItems}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <GridTextColumn
                    MappingName="CFieldDisplayName" />
                <GridTemplateColumn
                    CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateselctor}"
                    MappingName="CFieldValue" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>

Code Behind
    public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
    {
        public DataGridViewModel ViewModel { get; }

        public MyPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new DataGridViewModel();
        }
    }


    public class DataTemplateSelectorExt : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate TextBlockTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TextBoxTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate CheckBoxTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item) 
        { //This line is never his with a breakpoint
            if (item == null)
            {
                return TextBlockTemplate;
            }
            else if (item.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                return TextBoxTemplate;
            }
            else if (item.GetType() == typeof(bool))
            {
                return CheckBoxTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                return TextBoxTemplate;
            }
        }
    }

ViewModel

        public DataGridViewModel()
        {
            CustomInfoItems = new ObservableCollection<CustomInfo>();
            this.GenerateCutomInfoItems();
        }

        private void GenerateCutomInfoItems()
        {
            CustomInfoItems.Add(new CustomInfo() { CFieldDisplayName = "Custom TextBox Item", CFieldValue = "String Value" });
            CustomInfoItems.Add(new CustomInfo() { CFieldDisplayName = "Custom CheckBox Item", CFieldValue = true });
        }

    public class CustomInfo
    {
        public string CFieldDisplayName { get; set; }
        public object CFieldValue { get; set; }
    }


It is related to data grid. I suggest you could post the issue to the GitHub for better help.

As you can see in the doc, the DataTemplateSelector, the DataTemplateSelector has two overridable methods.

SelectTemplateCore(Object)
SelectTemplateCore(Object, DependencyObject)

In your case, try overriding the second one instead.

Thanks again @AndrewKeepCoding. The event triggers, but now my problem is that Object item in SelectTemplateCore is not being read as a string type and bool type per the GenerateCustomFieldItems method CFieldValue. Should I create a new question for this?

Yes. It's better 1 question per post.
